# How does the following summation evaluate to $n-i-1$?

Tags: summation

I have the following summation:
$$
\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}1=n-i-1
$$

I'm trying to understand how the summation evaluates to the expression $n-(i+1)$. Can someone show me algebraically how this is correct?

Comment: The sum is basically counting how many integers are in the set $\{i+1,i+2,...,n-1\}$. That is the same as the number of integers in the set $\{1,..,n-1\}$ minus the number of integers in $\{1,..,i\}$ or equivalently $(n-1)-i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see this: The index of summation is $j$. The starting value for $j$ is $i+1$, and the ending value is $n-1$. You are adding a $1$ for each occurrence of $j$. How many copies of $1$ are you adding up?

Define a new index $k:=j-i$. In words, to get the value for $k$, you take the value for $j$ and subtract $i$. So the starting value for $k$ is $(i+1)-i$, which equals $1$, and the ending value for $k$ is $(n-1)-i$. We conclude
$$
\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}1=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1-i}1 = n-1-i,
$$
since you are adding up $n-1-i$ copies of the value $1$.

---

You can use this device to obtain the general formula $\sum_{i=a}^b 1=b-a+1$.

There is also a pictorial illustration of the general formula:
$$\overbrace{\underbrace{1\quad 2\quad 3\quad \cdots\quad a-1}_{\text{$a-1$ items}}\quad a\quad a+1\quad \cdots\quad b-1\quad b}^{\text{$b$ items}}$$